# Indexing markdown documents for full text search in Apache SOLR

Tags: solr, full-text-search, markdown, apache-tika, full-text-indexing

I am using Apache SOLR to index markdown documents.
As you know, Markdown is basically plaintext with special tags for formatting like bold and italic.
The problem is: if the markdown has bold or italic formatting, the fulltext search is not working.  However, if the markdown document has no formatting elements (bold, italic or heading, links etc) - the full text search works. To summarize it works when markdown document is the same as the plain text(i.e no word has any markdown formatting).

I have concluded that I need to convert markdown to plaintext before indexing the documents. Only then the full text search will work as expected in all the cases.

 
I did some searching and reading on different online forums. I think I need to implement a custom analyzer. The custom analyzer needs to convert the markdown to plaintext first, and then index it. 
I think this situation is similar to what `Apache Tika` does for microsoft documents. It parses ms office documents and extracts the plain text.
I think I need to similar thing.

I think for markdown documents too - I need to parse and convert to plain text. 
 I have already found a way to convert markdown to plaintext.

However, I am not sure if I really need to create a custom analyzer. I read some code for custom analyzers - but all of them use `tokenFilters`. From my understanding, `tokenFilters` operate on the stream on a token by token basis. In my case, the entire `markdown` corpus has to be converted to `plain text`. So, please suggest an approach for this.

Another approach I have thought about this is to first convert the markdown to plaintext and then save the plaintext along with the markdown to the disk. But, I want to avoid this and handle this in SOLR. I expect that SOLR convert it to plain text and then index it.

1. Should I be creating a `custom analyzer` for saving the `markdown` documents to `plain text`? Or is a `custom query parser` required?
2. Can someone give a code example for the same (pseudocode is also fine).

Please help.

Comment: I can't see any reason why a [StandardTokenizer](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/tokenizers.html#Tokenizers-StandardTokenizer) shouldn't be able to give you proper Markdown-less tokens (as it'll split on and drop most non-alphanumeric characters). What part of the markdown syntax does it barf on?

Comment: @MatsLindh, I figured out the problem. I was using just the `WhiteSpaceAnalyzer`. `WhiteSpaceAnalyzer` was just tokenizing based on whitespace but not on special chars like * or ## in markdown. I see that for my usecase - `StandardTokenizerFactory` is perfect - as the tokenizer will break on whitespace as well as non-alphanumeric chars as mentioned by you. I have done this change - and now the search is working as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Use a StandardTokenizer](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/tokenizers.html#Tokenizers-StandardTokenizer) - it'll split on most non-numeric characters, which should be suitable for getting Markdown indexed as single terms, instead of with the Markdown syntax kept intact.

> This tokenizer splits the text field into tokens, treating whitespace and punctuation as delimiters. Delimiter characters are discarded, with the following exceptions:
>
> Periods (dots) that are not followed by whitespace are kept as part of the token, including Internet domain names.
>
> The "@" character is among the set of token-splitting punctuation, so email addresses are not preserved as single tokens.

If you want to split on periods between words as well, you can use a [PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/charfilterfactories.html#CharFilterFactories-solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory)
to insert a space after words separated by a dot without whitespace.